# R freezes when installing packages from package installer on Macbook

Tags: macos, r, package

I have been attempting to install some bioconductor packages in R on my Mac. However, when using the package installer, the application freezes and fails to respond. The same thing does NOT happen when I use the command line installer within R-the installer downloads and runs the package pretty much instantly.

Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks,
David

Comment: This is insufficient information for which to provide meaningful advice. Please read the R-help Posting Guide: http://www.r-project.org/posting-guide.html or other material on SO about how to ask a "good question".

Comment: Typically "freezes" just means that it is simply downloading+installing the package but you get feedback only after it is finished - there is no progress update.

Comment: I have seen the same thing happen when using the package installer inside Simon's R.app GUI, and came to the same conclusion as Simon suggested.  For whatever reason, it's often a lot faster to download the zip file from the cran.r-project.org (or mirror) site and tell the package installer to install from local source package.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek:  I have also experience the "endless wait" with BioC installs using the MacGUI. Sometimes the problem seems to reside in the number of cascaded dependencies that do not get well-handled across the R and BioC divide. It's not that big a deal. I still get a net advantage using the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

The Mac GUI doesn't provide any feedback until all packages have been successfully installed. Therefore it may appear to "freeze" while it is actually just waiting for the package installation process (download + install) to finish.

Note that BioC download is often very slow (and the packages can be big), so that's one of the main reasons why people tend to report this only with BioC.

Comment: I guess that must be it then. It's the only logical explanation. Thanks!

Comment: I also have the same issue on OS X when running the R binary from the terminal. May be a separate issue, but might not be. Still haven't figured out the root cause.